# Is "gypped" really (historically) a racist term?

Tags: etymology

It has only been recently that I have even been aware of the connection between "gypped" and "Gypsy". Perhaps because I've always seen it spelled with a "J", I had no idea that the word had racial undertones. Does it really? Was the word originally coined with Gypsies in mind?

Comment: It's not helpful to mark a duplicate without linking to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty commonly used slang word nowadays, which likely won't offend many people. However, its roots are clearly racist. Steer clear and use an alternative.